# Listen or wait for a specific time without using timer

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to listen or wait for a specific time (e.g. 11:30 am) every day. The only way I know how is to set a `timer` that checks for the current time every 60 seconds which I have actually implemented using a `backgroundworker`. But is there a way to just wait and listen for the specified time (similar to monitoring for directory changes) and then take some action?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, rather than having a program resident in memory waiting, you would setup a **Scheduled Task** for this (or a cron job on linux). The scheduled task will run the program at the appropriate time. The program can still check (validate) the expected time if needed, but it shouldn't just *always* sit in the background using up resources if it's only going to run once per day.

The scheduled task is also better because it will recover automatically from computer reboots, crashes, etc. If something happens that interrupts your program's normal running, the scheduled task will still be able to run.

This is especially important in the .Net world, because .Net requires you to be *very* careful writing long-lived programs to avoid address space fragmentation. The .Net garbage collector is good at freeing up and returning old memory to the operating system, but over time your program's virtual address space can become fragmented and eventually you will not be able to allocate new memory any longer.

Even if this is part of a larger program, where there are also other things happening based on user interactions, it's still a good idea to split this off into a separate process.

Comment: Good point regarding use of memory...but the application is not just running the same action everyday. Its a restaurant sales application with a happy hour feature, which can be set by the user to occur within any time frame. Could be everyday or every week. Could be one happy hour event in the morning and another in the evening. So I'm looking for a way to activate the discounted price when the event starts and deactivate as soon as it ends. You think task scheduler is still the way to go?

Comment: No, I don't. But I don't think you want to run any code to activate the special pricing, either. This needs to be DATA that is used when showing the menu options.

Comment: I agree with @JoelCoehoorn; if the app is a sales app and is usually in use, you can set a database table up called, say, `Discount` (or `HappyHour`, etc) and the user sets these times via their UI in that table. Then when a sale occurs the code works with the (eg) `Price` table and the `Discount` table to provide the correct price. That's how I'd approach it. (SQLite might be is a good option for this if you're not currently implementing an app DB.)

Comment: Thanks Joel and Steve. The idea was not to waste precious seconds during a sale in checking if a “happy hour” is active and if so whether its discount or “buy one get one free” etc plus a dozen other options and variations of the happy hour. I wanted to find a way to activate the happy hour when the time is up and set all variables, prices etc. So by the time a sale is happening, all variables are set, for the sake of speed.  But I guess the only way to go is to do the whole process at the point of a sale when I need to look up the price. Thanks guys.

Comment: Seconds? The time to do this is effectively zero. It's part of showing the menu on the Point Of Sale terminal or other display; the price there is just always correct.